# how do i put an image on top of an hr

Tags: html, css

I have tried 2-3 solutions, and it still didn't work.

it keeps overlapping the `<hr>` tag and I don't know how to keep it above the line 
I'm not able to send pictures yet, but I can send some test code that I tried

```css
div.box5 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0, 0, 0, 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Cog_font_awesome.svg/1200px-Cog_font_awesome.svg.png" alt="picture">
<div class="box5">
    <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you put the `<hr>` into a div instead of putting it by itself?

Comment: that's just some test code that i tried, not my actual code

Comment: Then please provide your actual code, so that we can know, what your actual problem is.

Comment: Your code does not overlap https://plnkr.co/edit/WWGD7Ih2RKJEcJIf

Comment: And please explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve. Do you mean you want the image to appear on top of the hr? That's what your title suggests, but then you state that the image keeps overlapping the hr which is a contradiction. Or do you simply want the image to appear at the top of the page and the hr appear under it? If you can provide more detail it will be easier to help figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you looking for? Please share your output so community can better help you.

```
<style>
 div.box5 {
 display: block;
 margin: 0, 0, 0, 0;
}
</style>
<div class="box5">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Cog_font_awesome.svg/1200px-Cog_font_awesome.svg.png" width=200 alt="picture">
<hr>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I cant get right what you are asking, but I think you are asking for keep the line above the image. Just type the `<hr>` tag above image.

Comment: OP wants to keep the image above the line. So, you have answered the opposite of what was asked.

Comment: I understand and I think there's no problem. The image is above the line already.